# Explain css syntax .apexp .detailList .list td

Tags: visualforce, css

I am reviewing someone else's css on a VF page.  I do not understand the syntax:

```
.apexp .detailList .list td {
    color: white;
}
```

I know it sets the td to white, but can someone explain how to construct the selector.  What is .apexp?  Why do we not just write:

```
td {
    color: white;
}
```

without the .apexp etc.?  I could not find any explanation of how to interpret this syntax so I can generate my own code.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Take a look at the many [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) available and in particular [CSS element element Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_element.asp). The author is taking care to make only specific TD elements white by relying on class names that Visualforce emits. (Use your browser's "View Source" to see those class names in the generated page.) This is a fragile but sometimes necessary approach.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I don't know what .apexp refers to?

Comment: Its a CSS class name that is probably an abbreviation for "apex page" that VF emits near the root of the page structure. Use your browser's "View Source" and then search for "apexp" and you should find it. Its probably a little redundant here in that ".detailList .list" ties this down to detail list parts of the page and pretty much the whole page is within the ".apexp" class element (if I remember correctly).

Comment: Thanks, Keith.  If you provide this as an answer I will credit you.

Comment: `<p class='apexp'><p class='detailList'><p class='list'><td>This is a white TD.</td></p></p></p> <td>This is normal.</td>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the many [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) available and in particular [CSS element element Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_element.asp). The author is taking care to make only specific TD elements white by relying on class names that Visualforce emits. (Use your browser's "View Source" to search for and see those class names in the generated page.) This is a fragile but sometimes necessary approach.

From the comment thread, "apexp" is a CSS class name that is probably an abbreviation for "apex page" that VF emits near the root of the page structure. It is probably a little redundant here in that ".detailList .list" ties this down to detail list parts of the page and pretty much the whole page is within the "apexp" class element (if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 4):

Two things to note:

- If you just use `td` as your selector, it will affect every table cell on the page. You want to make sure you only modify the DOM elements you expect.
- When working with multiple conflicting styles, the one with the greatest [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) wins. Using the most specific selector you can helps make sure they actually get applied.

Comment: I once worked on updating a jQuery mobile page that had 4 different CSS styles applied to it. Depending on where a view was called from the jQuery mobile tabs would be rounded (or not). No consistency on just that one view. It's totally up to the browser to decide which one wins.